# Maps API v3 - Chrome and Opera not showing markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Markers are showing correctly in Firefox, not in Chrome or Opera. I think i have some scope problem, as the `db_locations` array is 'sometimes' losing it's value and is arriving empty to `buildMap()`. I said 'sometimes' because when i add `alert(db_locations)` in `BuildMap()` in the first page refresh 'tends' to show the actual values.

Appreciate any help.

```
var db_locations = new Array();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "markers_xml.php",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
...
var inside = new Array(val1,val2,val3 etc);
db_locations[i]=inside;
...
});

function buildMap() { /* this is the init function */
...
setMarkers(map, db_locations);
...
}

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
// markers loop
}

window.onload = buildMap;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the AJAX request is not returning on time. Wrap the AJAX call in a function, call buildMap within the Ajax success function, and call the AJAX request wrapping function when the window loads.

Comment: A minor question for you: did you end up having the ajax call be sent on window.onload? I can't seem to think of an easy way so that the ajax request is sent before the window is loaded, but so that buildMap is called only after both the ajax request is called *and* the window is loaded. What did you end up doing?